# What does “so much as punch it in the face” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, syntactic-analysis

I am reading The Economist, and I do not understand one sentence.

> ALMOST one year into Donald Trump’s presidency, you have to pinch yourself to make sense of it all. In “Fire and Fury”, Michael Wolff’s gossipy tale of the White House, which did not welcome Mr Trump’s anniversary **so much as punch it in the face**, the leader of the free world is portrayed as a monstrously selfish toddler-emperor seen by his own staff as unfit for office ...

Here, What does “which did not welcome Mr Trump’s anniversary so much as punch it in the face” mean?
I thought the gossipy tale did not welcome the anniversary and it did not punch it either, but I am not sure.

Does it mean the tale did not welcome the anniversary as strong as it punched the anniversary? 
If so, why did the writer use “punch” instead of punched?

Could you please help me?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: (1) *"Does it mean the tale did not welcome the anniversary as strong as it punched the anniversary?*" __ yes you interpreted it right here (2) *"If so, why did the writer use “punch” instead of punched?"* __ "Punched" instead of "punch" might also be idiomatic here: *did not welcome (...) so much as **punched** it in the face...*

Comment: Yes indeed @Lee. It was not a welcome of the anniversary but a strong criticism. (But *you* are most welcome!)

Comment: @EnglishStudent  Thank you very much. Hope you have a great day.

Comment: We are always happy to help you @Lee, here on English Language and Usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it mean the tale did not welcome the anniversary as strong as it punched the anniversary? If so, why did the writer use “punch” instead of punched?

Yes. You can expand the original quote so that both sides include the subject and verb:

> [His tale did not] **welcome** Mr Trump’s anniversary so much as [his tale did] **punch** it in the face…

In the construction “*X* so much as *Y*”, *X* and *Y* must have the same form, and here that form is the infinitive, because of the auxiliary verb “did not”, which is *outside* the construction. One side is negative and the other is affirmative, but they’re not necessarily infinitive. For example:

> 1. He **didn’t answer** my question so much as **rephrase** it.
>
>    - He **didn’t** (**answer** so much as **rephrase**) my question.
> 2. They **didn’t sing** the words so much as **chant** them.
>
>    - They **didn’t** (**sing** so much as **chant**) the words.
> 3. She hurt me, by not so much what she **said** as what she **didn’t say**.

In #3, the past tense is indicated by the verbs “said” and “didn’t say”, *inside* the “…so much as…” phrase.

Comment: Thank you so much. So for #1, it means he rephrased my question but did not answer, and #3 means she hurt me with what she didn’t say and what she said to me didn’t hurt me as much as what she didn’t say? Sorry, I’m confused.

Comment: Yeah, you understood #1 right. For #3, maybe an example would help clarify. Imagine a boy says “I love you” to his girlfriend, and she replies “I know”—he might feel hurt, not because she *said* “I know”, but because she *didn’t* say “I love you” back to him. (Implying she doesn’t love him, or isn’t comfortable saying that she does.)